# undefined method `nested_set_options' in active_admin

Tags: activeadmin, rails-3.1

I have using awesome_nested_set with active_admin. But I found that active_admin can't find nested_set_options method

My active_admin code

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Category do
      form do |f|
        f.inputs "Category Details" do
          f.input :name,            :label => "Category name"
          f.input :parent_id,   :label => "Parent Category",    :as => :select, :collection => nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" }
        end
        f.buttons
      end 
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
:as => :select, :collection => f.template.nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" }
```

inside the aa ~ formtastic dsl bridge you can access view helpers from f.template